# Detecting if a non-printable character has been found - Perl

Tags: perl, file, character

My program is reading in a file, line by line. But if a non printable character is found (ex. characters with decimal value less than 32), then I just want to output an error message to the console.

Here is what I have

```
while($line=<FILE>){
print $line;
$line =~ s/^\s+//; #remove leading spaces
$line =~ s/\s+$//; #remove trailing spaces
if(/[\x00-\x1F]/){
    print "Found a non printable!";
}
```

I'm not sure if it is working, because I guess I'm not sure what the non printable would be in my file?

This is my current input file:

```
Pa$$word412
999
```

Wouldn't a carriage return be non-printable? Then shouldn't my warning message be printed?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317164/detect-whether-perl-string-is-printable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A carriage return is non-printable, by your definition; but you are removing the carriage return from your input when you say

```
$line =~ s/\s+$//; #remove trailing spaces
```

Comment: Ohhh I guess I wasn't fully understanding that! I commented those lines out, and then it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are reading the line into `$line` but not referencing this on your match. You would need to match `$line` explicitly like this:

```
if ($line =~ /[\x00-\x1F]/) {
```

Or, better yet, just put your line into `$_`:

```
while (<FILE>) {
    print;

    s/^\s+//; # remove leading spaces
    s/\s+$//; # remove trailing spaces

    if (/[\x00-\x1F]/) {
        print "WARNING -- Non-printables were found; they have been detected.";
    }
}
```

Trailing newlines will not trigger your warning because they match `\s` and are stripped by your trailing space removal. If you want a test case, put a tab character in your file; this should then match `[\x00-\x1F]`.